# Setting a variable equal to a return of function

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm trying to set a variable equal to a return of a function but I don't understand how can i do.
In particular this is the code:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.manager = new BleManager()

  this.state = {
    info: "",
    values: {}
  }

  this.deviceprefix = "FM_RAW";
  this.devicesuffix_dx = "DX";
}

model_dx(model) {
  return this.deviceprefix + model + this.devicesuffix_dx
}

if (device.name === "THERE i should use the return of model_dx") {
  this.info(device.id)
  this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
  device.connect()
```

I should check device.name with the result of the model_dx function. How can I do?
Thank you

Comment: try ```device.name === this.model_dx(yourModel)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about calling it? Create a instance of the object and call it:

```
 // Assume the name is CustomObj
 class CustomObj {
      constructor() {
           super();
           this.manager = new BleManager()
           this.state = {info: "", values: {}}
           this.deviceprefix = "FM_RAW";
           this.devicesuffix_dx = "DX";
      }

      model_dx(model) {
           return this.deviceprefix + model + this.devicesuffix_dx
      }
 }


 // I suppose this is outside of the object? Otherwise it would be out of scope anyways as you wrote your if in no function or whatsoever
 CustomObj obj = new CustomObj(); //<-- Create instance
 let alwaysdifferentParam = "model test";
 if (device.name === obj.model_dx(alwaysdifferentParam )) { //<-- Call it
      this.info(device.id)
      this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
      device.connect()
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! Only one question, the "model test" is a variable that i take from another page, so this value could always be different

Comment: doesnt matter just pass it as a variable then. Check out the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (device.name === this.model_dx('pass the desired value here')) {
  this.info(device.id)
  this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
  device.connect()
}
```